# GnuCOBOL Report Writer: syntax error, unexpected IS, expecting LEADING or TRAILING

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Installed GnuCOBOL version **3.0-rc1.0** to try out the recent Report Writer additions.
Attempting to compile the first listing *[with the PIC X(52) being a fix by me to the too-small PIC X(51) in the book]* in Chapter 18 of Beginning COBOL for Programmers by Michael Coughlan throws the errors:

```
Listing18-1.cbl:99: error: syntax error, unexpected IS, expecting LEADING or TRAILING
Listing18-1.cbl:99: error: PROCEDURE DIVISION header missing
Listing18-1.cbl:99: error: syntax error, unexpected .
Listing18-1.cbl:100: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:101: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:102: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:104: error: unknown statement '02'
Listing18-1.cbl:105: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:106: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:107: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:109: error: unknown statement '01'
Listing18-1.cbl:110: error: unknown statement '02'
Listing18-1.cbl:111: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:112: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:113: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:115: error: unknown statement '01'
Listing18-1.cbl:117: error: unknown statement '02'
Listing18-1.cbl:118: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:119: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:120: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:121: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:123: error: unknown statement '01'
Listing18-1.cbl:124: error: unknown statement '02'
Listing18-1.cbl:125: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:127: error: unknown statement '01'
Listing18-1.cbl:128: error: unknown statement '02'
Listing18-1.cbl:129: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:130: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:131: error: unknown statement '03'
Listing18-1.cbl:133: error: syntax error, unexpected PROCEDURE
Listing18-1.cbl: in paragraph 'PrintSalaryReport':
Listing18-1.cbl:153: error: 'DetailLine' is not defined
```

I think the first error reported may be the real problem, with the others being a knock-on effect.
Here is the complete program listing:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. Listing18-1.
AUTHOR. Michael Coughlan.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT SalesFile ASSIGN TO "Listing18-1-Sales.DAT"
        ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

    SELECT PrintFile ASSIGN TO "Listing18-1.Rpt".

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD SalesFile.
01 SalesRecord.
   88 EndOfFile     VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
   02 StateNum      PIC 99.
   02 SalesAgentNum PIC 999.
   02 ValueOfSale   PIC 9(5)V99.

FD PrintFile
   REPORT IS SolaceSalesReport.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 StateNameTable.
   02 StateNameValues.
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Alabama".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Alaska".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Arizona".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Arkansas".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "California".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Colorado".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Connecticut".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Delaware".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Florida".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Georgia".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Hawaii".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Idaho".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Illinois".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Indiana".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Iowa".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Kansas".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Kentucky".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Louisiana".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Maine".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Maryland".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Massachusetts".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Michigan".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Minnesota".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Mississippi".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Missouri".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Montana".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Nebraska".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Nevada".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "New Hampshire".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "New Jersey".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "New Mexico".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "New York".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "North Carolina".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "North Dakota".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Ohio".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Oklahoma".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Oregon".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Pennsylvania".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Rhode Island".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "South Carolina".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "South Dakota".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Tennessee".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Texas".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Utah".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Vermont".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Virginia".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Washington".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "West Virginia".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Wisconsin".
      03 FILLER PIC X(14) VALUE "Wyoming".
   02 FILLER REDEFINES StateNameValues.
      03 State OCCURS 50 TIMES.
         04 StateName   PIC X(14).

REPORT SECTION.
RD SolaceSalesReport
   CONTROLS ARE StateNum
                SalesAgentNum
   PAGE LIMIT IS 54
   FIRST DETAIL 3
   LAST DETAIL 46
   FOOTING 48.

01 TYPE IS REPORT HEADING NEXT GROUP PLUS 1.
   02 LINE 1.
      03 COLUMN 20      PIC X(32) VALUE "Solace Solar Solutions".

   02 LINE 2.
      03 COLUMN 6       PIC X(52) VALUE "Sales Agent - Sales and Salary Report Monthly Report".

01 TYPE IS PAGE HEADING.
   02 LINE IS PLUS 1.
      03 COLUMN 2   PIC X(5)    VALUE "State".
      03 COLUMN 16  PIC X(5)    VALUE "Agent".
      03 COLUMN 32  PIC X(8)    VALUE "Value".

   02 LINE IS PLUS 1.
      03 COLUMN 2   PIC X(4)    VALUE "Name".
      03 COLUMN 16  PIC X(6)    VALUE "Number".
      03 COLUMN 31  PIC X(8)    VALUE "Of Sales".

01 DetailLine TYPE IS DETAIL.
   02 LINE IS PLUS 1.
      03 COLUMN 1   PIC X(14)       SOURCE StateName(StateNum).
      03 COLUMN 17  PIC ZZ9         SOURCE SalesAgentNum.
      03 COLUMN 30  PIC $$$,$$$.99  SOURCE ValueOfSale.

01 SalesAgentGrp
   TYPE IS CONTROL FOOTING SalesAgentNum NEXT GROUP PLUS 2.
   02 LINE IS PLUS 1.
      03 COLUMN 15      PIC X(21)   VALUE "Sales for sales agent".
      03 COLUMN 37      PIC ZZ9     SOURCE SalesAgentNum.
      03 COLUMN 43      PIC X       VALUE "=".
      03 TotalAgentSales COLUMN 45 PIC $$$$$,$$$.99 SUM ValueOfSale.

01 StateGrp TYPE IS CONTROL FOOTING StateNum NEXT GROUP PLUS 2.
   02 LINE IS PLUS 1.
      03 COLUMN 1       PIC X(58) VALUE ALL "-".

01 TYPE IS PAGE FOOTING.
   02 LINE IS 49.
      03 COLUMN 1       PIC X(29)   VALUE "Programmer - Michael Coughlan".
      03 COLUMN 55      PIC X(6)    VALUE "Page :".
      03 COLUMN 62      PIC ZZ9     SOURCE PAGE-COUNTER.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
Begin.
    OPEN INPUT SalesFile
    OPEN OUTPUT PrintFile

    READ SalesFile
        AT END SET EndOfFile TO TRUE
    END-READ

    INITIATE SolaceSalesReport

    PERFORM PrintSalaryReport UNTIL EndOfFile

    TERMINATE SolaceSalesReport

    CLOSE SalesFile, PrintFile

    STOP RUN.

PrintSalaryReport.
    GENERATE DetailLine

    READ SalesFile
        AT END SET EndOfFile TO TRUE
    END-READ.
```

I get the same problem on 3 different machines: a 64-bit desktop running Mint Cinnamon, a 64-bit laptop running Ubuntu, and an old 32-bit Netbook running Lubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think the first error reported may be the real problem, with the others being a knock-on effect.

Yes, that's exactly the case.
GnuCOBOL 3.0-rc-1 does not support `LINE IS PLUS` - either adjust to `LINE PLUS` or update to a 3.1 version available as [release](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnucobol/).

To query the current version of GnuCOBOL use `cobc --version` (or the short `cobc -V` <-upper case).

Comment: Great, thanks for that, I'll try out as soon as I'm free.

Comment: As expected, installation of the 3.1 development tarball did indeed compile the program, and successfully produce the report.

Comment: Quick question: How to tell what version of GNU COBOL is installed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.